# CodeIgniter : How to receive serialize post data in array on RESTful Server?

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, rest, codeigniter

i want to ask, how to receive data from serialize data in array on CodeIgniter RESTful Server ?

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/mywebsite/api/index.php/purchase",
    data: $("#formdatatrans").serialize(),
    success: function(response) {
        alert("Success");
    }
});
```

**Html Form**

```
<input type="text" name="data1[]">
<input type="text" name="data2[]">
<input type="text" name="data3[]">
<input type="text" name="data4[]">
```

**Controller**

```
function index_post() {       
$data = array(
            'data1'           => $this->post('data1'),
            'data2'       => $this->post('data2'),
            'data3'             => $this->post('data3'),
            'data4'    => $this->post('data4'));
$insert = $this->db->insert('table1', $data);
if ($insert) {
$this->response($data, 200);
} else {
$this->response(array('status' => 'fail', 502));
}}
```

**Input Data**

```
Array [0]
Data1 = abc_1
Data2 = abc_1
Data3 = abc_1
Data4 = abc_1

Array [1]
Data1 = abc_2
Data2 = abc_2
Data3 = abc_2
Data4 = abc_2
```

How to add all of the data above in one time using for / while looping ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Merges** with Merges you can convert two arrays into an array

```
<?php
$array1 = array('Data1' =>"abc_1",'Data2' =>"abc_1",'Data3' =>"abc_1",'Data4' =>"abc_1");
$array2=array('Data5' =>"abc_2",'Data6' =>"abc_2",'Data7' =>"abc_2",'Data8' =>"abc_2");
$data  = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($output);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your controller with this and check this will help you for one time insert using foreach loop.

```
function index_post() {       

    $data1 = $this->post('data1');
    $data2 = $this->post('data2');
    $data3 = $this->post('data3');
    $data4 = $this->post('data4');

    foreach ($data1 as $key=> $value) {
        $data['data1'] = $data1[$key];
        $data['data2'] = $data2[$key];
        $data['data3'] = $data3[$key];
        $data['data4'] = $data4[$key];
        $insert = $this->db->insert('table1', $data);
    }

    if ($insert) {
        $this->response($data, 200);
    } else {
        $this->response(array('status' => 'fail', 502));
    }
}
```